# Does Google offer a support number for the Android OS as a whole? If not, why?

Tags: stock-android

My grandfather's contacts are missing on his Galaxy, and a quick Google search on the error "Sync is currently experiencing problems. It will be back shortly." shows numerous results, solutions, etc etc, none of which seem to be applicable in this situation.

Now, obviously I could ask here, but that guarantees no quick solution, and the contacts are needed soon to make important calls. I looked into Google Support, and that page doesn't offer an option for support with the Android OS in general. Instead, it sends you to support at Samsung.com, since this is a Galaxy, and that page is a dead end in regards to my problem.

We dont have time to wait for an answer from a support forum or ticket. I'd like to just get on the phone and call Google for a general Android OS issue. Is this possible? Where can I find the number? I've looked everywhere.

Comment: If your contact is synced to Google, then I think you should be able to see the contact on [Google Contacts](https://www.google.com/contacts/) from your browser. Indeed, Google doesn't have help support for Android in general.

Comment: @AndrewT. Well on that note, I'll sure never buy an Android. Apple is ready to help me with these problems. https://getsupport.apple.com

Comment: The phone manufacturers anyway have their own support site where you can contact for help regarding your mobile issues. For instance Motorola, https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com and for Sony http://support.sonymobile.com/ etc. For Samsung, you could try http://www.samsung.com/support/

Comment: @Lucky But Samsung isn't in charge of resolving Android OS issues, they dont control the software or Google Contact Sync in this case. If you visit that support page you'll find no such support offered in regards to Android problems in general. So Google has created an OS for which it offers no fast support for - an industry standard that even Apple follows, offerring fast over-the-phone support for any problems with iOS. This is not a user friendly decision by Google, very dissapointed, my grandfather cant make calls and I have to wait for a support ticket response.

Comment: @JonathanTodd Here's a related post on Google Product Forums https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/uHRNJLZwp7k and also try this app [Contacts Sync Fix](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.ivary.ContactsSyncFix) to recover your lost contacts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Google does not provide a general service support number. Google provides the base Android operating system with components like a contacts manager. Both the phone manufacturer and the service provider may customize the OS, use their own applications, or replace stock applications like the contacts manager. Google is not able to support these customizations.

In the US, I would expect the best tech support service to be from your carrier at local stores. They are the ones with dedicated personnel who can physically touch your phone and show you how to do things.

Comment: Oh I see. This seems unusual, but knowing that, the lack of support would make sense. By the way, good luck getting support from Samsung, I just called and it sounded like a sweatshop with 50 people sitting shoulder to shoulder talking with accents. There was so much chatter in the background that I couldnt hear the rep at all and finally had to just hang up.